# Python spark: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapr

I'm working on `spark` and `python`.

When I call any action on `csv` file, it gives me `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

here is code snippet.

```
test_rdd = sc.textFile("/mapr/data/airflow-test.csv").map(lambda line: line.split())
print(test_rdd.first())
print(test_rdd.count())
```

Here is full Traceback.

```
File "pysparktask.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(test_rdd.first())
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1328, in first
    rs = self.take(1)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1310, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/context.py", line 933, in runJob
    port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2403, in _jrdd
    self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2336, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2315, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 428, in dumps
  return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 657, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 409, in dump
    self.save(obj)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 751, in save_tuple
    save(element)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 204, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 241, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 781, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 805, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 204, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 241, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 781, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 808, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 204, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 234, in save_function_tuple
    code, f_globals, defaults, closure, dct, base_globals = self.extract_func_data(func)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 296, in extract_func_data
    func_global_refs = self.extract_code_globals(code)
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 278, in extract_code_globals
    out_names.add(names[oparg])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

any suggestions?

Comment: @Prune, right and he is trying to read csv file which is comma separated Also `sc` is sparkContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using unsupported Python version. As of today no released version, including Spark 2.0.1, supports Python 3.6.

You should downgrade Python 3.5 or patch with https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17374

Detailed description of the problem can be found in [SPARK-19019](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019)

Comment: To mitigate SPARK-19019 the below line can be added in 

$SPARK_HOME/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/serializers.py

 cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs, verbose=False, rename=False, module=None)